# Response returned by Route53 shows no Error, yet when I try to acess on browser, no response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I created a hosted zone for my domain, I transferred DNS service to Amazon Route 53, Checked response from Route 53 and it showed:

```
DNS request sent to Route 53
mywebsite.com.br. IN NS
EDNS0 client subnet IP
24
DNS response code NOERROR
Protocol UDP
Response returned by Route 53
ns-9999.awsdns-99.org.
ns-9999.awsdns-99.co.uk.
ns-999.awsdns-99.com.
ns-99.awsdns-99.net.
```

Which is correct,
and I created a router that acess my beanstalk, like this:

```
DNS response code,
NOERROR
Protocol
UDP
Response returned by Route 53
MYBEANSTALKIP
MYBEANSTALKIP
```

All seems correct, expect the fact I can't acess it, and when I try to ping, open on browse, all it show is a incorrect URL message.
I even tried to use https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/ to check it, nothing at all.
Did I miss any step?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution:

Wait a few hours.

Comment: Yet AWS docs advertise a 60-second turn over.... >:|

Comment: It seems like it is 48 hours based on the time to live in seconds (TTL) I see

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I needed to eliminate the initial configuration that Route53 had left by default, and create a new zone.  I had not updated the NS that has the DNS provider of Route 53. For that reason my DNS never spread until the update works.
[image]